# URL Encode in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
var pid = $('#pid').val();
        var pname = $('#pname').val() + " " + $('#varient_title').val() + " " + $('#varient_value').val();
        var price = $('#price').val();
        var shipping = $('#shipping').val(); 
  $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/cart.php?pid=" + pid + "&pname=" + pname + "&price=" + price + '&shipping=' + shipping,
        type: "GET",
```

In ajax call i want to encode pname ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: encodeURI(pname)    this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

> Try This

```
var pid = $('#pid').val();
    var pname = $('#pname').val() + " " + $('#varient_title').val() + " " + $('#varient_value').val();
    var price = $('#price').val();
    var shipping = $('#shipping').val(); 
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/cart.php?pid=" + pid + "&pname=" + encodeURI(pname) + "&price=" + price + '&shipping=' + shipping,
    type: "GET",
```

Comment: awsome @DivyaSantoshi

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using `POST`. Also you can change type to `GET`. Also you json format for encoding and decoding `pname` parameter:

```
    var pid = $('#pid').val();
    var price = $('#price').val();
    var shipping = $('#shipping').val(); 

    var pname = {
         pname: $('#pname').val(),
         varient_title: $('#varient_title').val(),
         varient_value: $('#varient_value').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/cart.php",
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'html',
        data: {
            pid: pid ,
            pname : JSON.stringify(pname),
            price : price,
            shipping: shipping,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success")
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Ajax', 'Error', textStatus);
        },
    });
```

Comment: encodeURI(pname)---this worked for me tanq for helping